# Why does String have a parameter-less constructor in Java?

Tags: java

From documentation:

> [`public String()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String())
>
> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents an empty character sequence. **Note that use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.**

Did it have any use in previous Java versions?

Comment: `String(String original)` has a similar note

Comment: Similarly `String.copyValueOf(char[] data)` is documented as "Equivalent to `String.valueOf(data)`. It seems a pre-1.0 early version of Java didn't have immutable strings.

Comment: No. It's a misconception from the early days of Java. But Java has always tried to stay backwards compatible, so these constructors are left there.

Comment: @tkausl The difference is that `original != new String(original)`.

Comment: It could be historical, but it could just be another of those little idiosyncrasies with which Java abounds, like having a NullPointerException without having pointers.

Comment: `String(String)` did have some use pre-Java7 and the note says "unless ..." unlike this one.